# test R extension without R

Tags: r, googletest, rcpp, armadillo, testthat

I have been working on extension to R that is going to do some clustering. The project uses c++ and Rcpp (calculations are performed using RcppArmadillo). As a result I have a few classes I need to test. I was suggested to use googletest. Unfortunately, I fail to run any testing code.

The problem is that in order to test classes that use Rcpp with googletest framework I have to work outside of R environment.

I mean I do not transform data into standard c++ data structures like vector. The dataset is supposed to be enormous. I get NumericMatrix with data and I pass it down. That causes all c++ classes to use Rcpp.h (or armadillo). I wonder if I can use these classes outside of R.

I was looking for any information on standalone programs that use Rcpp as a library but all I get is 'standalone' code as opposite to c++ code compiled directly in R command line interface by inline package. I would prefer to work with googletest because I can test c++ directly.

The question is whether one can use Rcpp without R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a strict sense, you can't because Rcpp code is meant to be called from R.

In a wider sense, of course you can *provided you write your interfaces correctly*. Write C++ code that does *not* depend on R and Rcpp headers, using just C++ and STL and Armadillo and maybe googletest idioms. Ie do not use Rcpp types such as as `Rcpp::NumericMatrix` but use Armadillo types such as `arma::mat`. Test the living daylight out of them.  Maybe wrap them up in a library.

Then just write a thin access layer using Rcpp and RcppArmadillo. Et voila -- you have tested code, accessed in R.

Comment: No, you don't. The default convector reuses the R memory.  Just read the documentation, or previous discussions, or simply memory profile it.